# Error Unsatisfied requirement(s): in Camel servicemix for requirement com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc

Tags: java, sql, apache-servicemix

I am Getting bellow error while running in servicemix
I am doing Sql opeartion using JDBC Driver in camel it BUILD SUCCESSFULLY but when i run its giving   Error

```
Unsatisfied requirement com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
**Error executing command: Can't install feature examples-camel-sql-derby/0.0.0:
Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
    package:(&(package=org.apache.camel.example.sql))
    Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: Camel SQL :: Datasource Derby

    package:(&(package=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc))
    Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: Camel SQL :: Orders
```

Please help

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you describe step by step what you are doing? Which feature are you installing? One of the existing? Your own feature?

Comment: I can see you are installing the `examples-camel-sql-derby` feature but you have probably changed it and now it references the sqlserver drive. You must install the driver together with the feature. Please check if the jar with the drive is an OSGi bundle. If not install it using `wrap` protocol